Is it possible to remove the background of the iframe pdf previewer or set it to white?
I have a PDF Preview in HTML. I have a iframe tag. However in the browser I get a black PDF Preview Background. On the mobile Version this does not appear.
Here my code:


<iframe src="/loadsheet/LOADSHEET_LX-AIM [PA-44-180]_27_04_2024_00_56.pdf#toolbar=0" frameborder="0" id="metricImage" style="height: 35vh"></iframe>




